# Help with understanding 「すそをはじく ように引っ張ると」 in sentence

Tags: relative-clauses

The full sentence is this:

> 撥水がすごいので屋内に入る前に着たまますそをはじくように引っ張ると水を払うことが出来る。

The part I am having trouble with is:

> すそをはじくように引っ張ると

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

It's to vigorously pull the lower part of the raincoat in order to shake the rain off the raincoat. はじく is to flick or snap. This is something you may do *after* you used your raincoat. The sentence basically says the water-shedding quality of the coat is so great that [you only have to shake it to dry it](https://youtu.be/ZelFfiwDbD4?t=20s).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, flip/fold the sleeves on your shirt/trousers that you are currently wearing in order to shorten them/pull them back so that you can toss out the water without soiling them.

I hope this helped.

Comment: the idiom in English is to roll up you sleeves or trousers.

Comment: The ように in はじく**ように**ひっぱると… here is not "so that~~ / in order to~~" (≂はじくために) but "like~~ / as if ~~" (≂はじくようにして・はじくような感じで).　・・・つまり「はじくような感じで、すそを（ピンっと）ひっぱる」ってことです・・